# 3d plot to plot 3dimensional object using a function in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I cannot seem to plot a 3d object using a function.

Can you help me please?

Here is my code below:

The code asks for matplotlib, then there is the function and the intervals and the plot section.

```
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab as p
import numpy as np

fig = p.figure()
ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)

def f(x,y,z):
    return (x**3) * (y**5) *z

x = np.arange(1.0, 2.0, 0.1)
y = np.arange(1.0, 4.0, 0.1)
z = np.arange(1.0, 2.0, 0.1)


ax.plot_surface(f(x,y,z))

ax.set_xlim3d([-10, 10])
ax.set_xlabel('X')

ax.set_ylim3d([-10, 10])
ax.set_ylabel('Y')

ax.set_zlim3d([-10, 10])
ax.set_zlabel('Z')


p.show()
```

The error is as follows:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dell\Downloads\test3dv4.py", line 17, in 
    ax.plot_surface(f(x,y,z))
  File "C:\Users\dell\Downloads\test3dv4.py", line 10, in f
    return (x**3) * (y**5) *z
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,) (30,)

Comment: Please add the specific error to the question

Comment: To plot `f` as a function of `x`, `y`, `z` you would need 4 dimensions.

Comment: xyz are 3 dimensions in space using cartesian coordinates. Do you mean computer (python) syntax?

Comment: Firstly - don't use `pylab`! It's outdated and confusing if you're just starting out.  Your already use `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` - just use that directly.  As unutbu says, you really have a 4 dimensional case here - `f(x,y,z)` is a function of all three spatial co-ordinates.  One convention in this case is to use colour to represent the value of `f(x,y,z)` at different points in 3D space - e.g. a scatter plot with different colours.  Or - maybe - in reality your function should be `f(x,y)` and output `z` - in which case you can plot a surface. We need more context to help...

Comment: The function f(x,y,z) is a triple integral equation to be solved. I want to plot the volume under the xyz curve.